# Find the critical points of $g(x,y) = 4x^{3} - 12xy + 3y^{2} - 18y -5.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have the function $g(x,y) = 4x^{3} - 12xy + 3y^{2} - 18y -5.$ The only critical points that I have found for this function are $(-1, 1)$, and $(3, 9)$. But my professor insisted that there are more critical points besides these two.

Can anyone help me find them please?

Comment: wolfram alpha gives that those two points you list are indeed the only critical points for $g$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will tell my professor.

Comment: Why not publish you answer so that it can be inspected closely?

Answer (score 1):

The critical points occur where the gradient of the scalar field is zero. In this case

$\nabla g(x,y)=(12x^2-12y, 6y-12x-18)=\overrightarrow{0}$

If you solve this system of equations you'll find that the only two points are

$(-1, 1)$ and $(3, 9)$

As a consequence of the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), these are the only two solutions.

Comment: The system of equations can be interpreted as the intersection of a parabola and line, which can have at most two intersection points.